# Embedded system: How to identify required tasks/threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded, real-time

I'm studying embedded programming, so I'm new in this field.
Can someone explain how to identify tasks/threads from given system description. Also, how can I estimate timing constraints, execution times... I'm really stuck.

Here is system description I'm working on:

Implement a 2 degree of freedom servo motor system. A two-axis joystick is used for controlling servo motors. Additionally, enable recording and reproducing the user path of the joystick, so that identical movement could be replicated multiple times. It is necessary to support the recording of 3 motion profiles with a length of at least 5 minutes. The profile needs to be recorded to a non-volatile memory, and the recording/playback control via the joystick button. Provide appropriate signalling for the current selected profile and operating mode (recording / playback) using one LED for each profile. In the RT-Thread system realize the necessary drivers on the Raspberry Pi Pico platform as support for the devices used and the application itself that implements the described system with clear separated threads for each of the observed functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

It is tempting to partition functionally, but in practice you should partition based on deadlines, determinism and update rates.  For simple systems, that may turn out to be the same as a functional partitioning. The part:

> clear separated threads for each of the observed functionalities

May lead you to an inappropriate partitioning.  However that may be the partitioning your tutor expects even if it is sub-optimal.

There is probably no single solution, but obvious *candidates* for tasks are:

- Joystick reader,
- Servo controller,
- Recorder,
- Replayer.

Now considering these *candidates*, it can be seen that the joystick control and replay control are mutually exclusive, and also that replay itself is selected through the joystick button.  Therefore it makes sense to make that a single task.  Not least because the replayer will communicate with the servo controller in the same way as the joystick.  So you might have:

- Joystick reader / replayer,
- Servo controller,
- Recorder.

The recorder is necessarily a separate thread because access to NV memory may be slower and non-deterministic.  You would need to feed time and x/y position data in a message queue of sufficient length to ensure the recording does not affect the timing motion control.

It is not clear what king of servo you are using or if your application is responsible for the PID motion control or simply sends a position signal to a servo controller.  If the latter, there may be no reason to separate teh servo control from the reader/replayer.  In which case you would have:

- Joystick reader / replayer / Servo controller,
- Recorder.

Other solutions are possible.  For example the recorder might record the servo position over time rather the joystick position, and have the servo controller handle replay.

- Joystick reader,
- Servo controller / replayer,
- Recorder.

That makes sense if the Joystick polling and Servo update rates differ, because you'd what to replay what the servo did, not what the joystick did.

Comment: Thanks @Clifford for detailed and clear answer. I'm using HS-422 RC servo motor. Raspberry only needs to output PWM signal for controlling the servo. Also, could you give me some good reading material from which I could learn? I'm having tough time dealing with this. Thanks

Comment: @AleksandarSimonović : I've been doing this of over 30 years; I am my own resource, I cannot recommend any particular resource for such a specific question, and such requests are off-topic on SO. Google is your friend; I took a quick look and came up with https://www.embedded.com/using-design-patterns-to-identify-and-partition-tasks-in-an-rtos-environment-part-3/ . I have not read it in full, but articles on embedded.com are generally of high quality, written by professional practitioners, rather than well meaning enthusiasts. You might also look for articles on _rate monotonic scheduling_.

Comment: @AleksandarSimonović Notably, Rasp PI with multi-threading is completely overkill and needlessly complex for this task. Proper design is to write down the requirements first, then pick a system later. Not "pick a tool and then start up a project" - yeah, you could probably drive in screws with your hammer but wouldn't it be better to use a screwdriver? A bare metal, low-end MCU would do just fine. ->

Comment: When picking a MCU, nail down the most exotic requirement first. In this case it seems (at a glance) that writing to NVM on the fly is your toughest requirement. You'll need a part with fast data flash/eeprom and you'll need to consider data retention due to repeated writes. You'd be looking at data flash minimum erase segment sizes and erase time, then the number of write cycles of the memory. In case you want to implement proportional control of the servo with PID, then it is also important to look at ADC resolution and pick a fairly quick MCU. I'd go with a Cortex M of some flavour.

Comment: @Lundin I am assuming from the way the question is worded, that this is an academic exercise and this is the "course platform".  You have to start somewhere and such assignments are necessarily somewhat contrived and unnecessary.  Nonetheless your comments are probably better written against the question, they are not relevant to this answer.

Comment: If so, that's a pretty big school assignment. Final thesis or such maybe. Also I just realized that "Pico" is the Cortex M0+ microcontroller version, not the Linux bloat version. That's a far more sensible platform.

Comment: No, this is not final thesis assignment, this is assignment for academic subject (real time programming). We have to use Raspberry Pico. After reading Pico documentation I realized Pico is based on RP2040 MCU which has no non volatile memory. Am I correct? Any ideas how can I work around this lack?

Comment: @AleksandarSimonović Where do you think your code goes?  It has 2MB of QSPI flash _on-board_ (not _on chip_).  The flash is a Winbond W25Q16JV . It is complicated by the fact that you cannot program the flash whilst executing code from it (QSPI XiP).  You have to run the programming code in SRAM and ensure that no flash resident interrupts occur or if the vector table is in flash.  It is however supported by the C/C++ SDK (SDK user manual §4.1.9). Alternatively you add a separate memory such as SPI or I2C Flash, EEPROM or FRAM, or even an SD card.  But all that warrants a different question.

Comment: Well, it surely sound like a medium course semester project. I once did a LCD driver on am SBC, and in another semester a USB stack on a HC08 with ext. USB chip (at this time there was no integration yet), including some soldering of external HW. Another did a solitaire halma with where some coil on 3 ropes controlled by servos move the pieces around. Also with a HC08. As he said, he had just 36 bytes RAM left, I said it just fits for an undo stack for this (each step with 4bit x/y) ... Compared to this, the Raspberry sounds almost luxurious. :)